# The left hand side of a binary predicate cannot be a literal expression, it must be a valid property or functional predicate expression: PropertyName

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I am new to breeze js. My spa app is using breeze, Knockout, EF and the MVC framework.

My POCO entity definition is

```
public partial class Tbl_GLB_Library
    {
        System.Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> Size { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastWriteTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastAccessTime { get; set; }
        public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

At the client side, I add an unmapped property using a custom constructor:

```
function addTbl_GLB_LibrariesProperties() {
        var metadataStore = Manager.metadataStore;
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Tbl_GLB_Library', null, Tbl_GLB_LibraryInit);

        function Tbl_GLB_LibraryInit(Library) {
            Library.FileContent = ko.observable();
        }
    }
```

After fetching metadata and some data, I need to query on the cached data.

```
 query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Tbl_GLB_Library").where(breeze.Predicate.create('FileContent', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Equals, null));

return Manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

This scenario works for all mapped properties, but for `FileContent`, which is an unmapped property, an exception was thrown! How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting NamingConvention to camelCase?  This error message will come up if the left hand expresssion of the predicate is the wrong case.  Just try changing it to fileContent and you'll quickly know if that is the problem.

Comment: I'm using PascalCase and not change settings of breeze. by default NameConvention value is "NamingConvention.none" that means "no change".